# ActiveMQ Request-Reply timeout

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have this activeMQ issue where I send a request to a remote broker (from a Camel Application). See config below:

```
<bean id="providerJMSConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="alwaysSessionAsync" value="false"/>
    <property name="alwaysSyncSend" value="true"/>
    <property name="brokerURL"><value>${remote-broker-url}</value></property>
    <property name="clientID" value=""/>
    <property name="closeTimeout" value="150000"/>
    <property name="copyMessageOnSend" value="true"/>
    <property name="disableTimeStampsByDefault" value="false"/>
    <property name="dispatchAsync" value="false"/>
    <property name="objectMessageSerializationDefered" value="false"/>
    <property name="optimizeAcknowledge" value="true"/>
    <property name="optimizedMessageDispatch" value="true"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="producerWindowSize" value="0"/>
    <property name="statsEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="false"/>
    <property name="useCompression" value="false"/>
    <property name="useRetroactiveConsumer" value="false"/>
    <property name="userName" value=""/>
    <property name="watchTopicAdvisories" value="true"/>
    <property name="sendTimeout" value="0"/>
</bean>

<bean id="aeroProviderJMSConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="providerJMSConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="true"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>      
    <property name="priority" value="${jms-message-priority}"/>
    <property name="acceptMessagesWhileStopping" value="false"/>    
</bean>
<bean id="providerJMS" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="providerJMSConfig"/>        
</bean>

 <osgi:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true">
   <endpoint id="providerEndpoint" uri="providerJMS:queue:provider?replyTo=providerResponse&requestTimeout=120000"/>
       <route>
    <from .....>
     <to ref="providerEndpoint"/>
   ....
    </route>
```

Whenever I check the "providerResponse" queue on the remote broker, I realise the resposne message is never picked up. it remains in the message even I had asked response messages be queued in there (which was actually done).

My question is, why will the Camel refuse to get this message from this queue?
Note that Exchange pattern was explicitly set to InOut.

I noticed it said the CorrelationID were not the same even though I check the JMSCorrelationID for the request and the response which look the same to me.

Is there an alternate Selector I can use for matching JMS Request/Reply response?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `<to ref="providerEndpoint"/>` try `<inOut ref="providerEndpoint"/>`. If you omit the replyTo parameter on the URI, Camel wil create a temporary queue to be used for that response only.

Comment: Can you connect jconsole or visualvm to that ActiveMQ instance via JMX, browse the queue, and paste a copy of one of the messages into this thread?

Comment: BooleanProperties:
ByteProperties
DoubleProperties
FloatProperties
IntProperties
JMS Correlation ID: ID-WEBESBSTAGING-3245-1321373681481-1-51
JMSDeliveryMode:PERSISTENT
JMSDestination: queue://aeroReply
JMSExpiration: 0
JMSMessageID: ID:TestESB-1233-1321373526837-24:1:18:254:1
JMSPriority: 9
JMSRedelivered: false
JMSReplyTo: queue://reply
JMSTimestamp: Tue Nov 15 20:02:40 GMT+01:00 2011
JMSType: null
JMSXGroupID: null
JMSXGroupSeq: 0
LongProperties:
OriginalDestination:
PropertiesText:
ShortProperties:
StringProperties:
Text: <?xml version="1.0"?>